Local and Global Variables Setting Inquiry
Why do I get the following error on the code below and how do I fix it?
CS0136: Local or parameters named 'yeniPoz' cannot be declared in this range because this name is used to surround local ranges to define local or parameters.
  private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
   if (other.CompareTag("ts"))
     {
      Vector3 yeniPoz = new Vector3(transform.position.x, .23f, transform.position.z);

        GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>().YokOlmaEfektiOlustur(yeniPoz);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);

    if (other.CompareTag("os"))
         {
            Vector3 yeniPoz = new Vector3(transform.position.x, .23f, transform.position.z);

            GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>
            ().YokOlmaEfektiOlustur(yeniPoz);            
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

    if (other.CompareTag("cs"))
        {             
            Vector3 yeniPoz = new Vector3(transform.position.x, .23f, transform.position.z);

            GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>
            ().YokOlmaEfektiOlustur(yeniPoz);
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }


Your first 'if' body not closed.

You cannot declare a local variable if a variable with the same name has already been declared above.
In your case, the first if statement hasn't been closed, which makes the code think that the other yeniPozs are in the same block as the 1st one.
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("ts"))
    {
        Vector3 yeniPoz = new Vector3(transform.position.x, .23f, transform.position.z);

        GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>().YokOlmaEfektiOlustur(yeniPoz);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    if (other.CompareTag("os"))
    {
        Vector3 yeniPoz = new Vector3(transform.position.x, .23f, transform.position.z);

        GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>().YokOlmaEfektiOlustur(yeniPoz);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    if (other.CompareTag("cs"))
    {
        Vector3 yeniPoz = new Vector3(transform.position.x, .23f, transform.position.z);

        GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>().YokOlmaEfektiOlustur(yeniPoz);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}


Additionally, make sure you don't write the same code more than once. Simply extend the condition to check the ts, os and cs tags.
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("ts") || other.CompareTag("os") || other.CompareTag("cs"))
    {
        Vector3 yeniPoz = new Vector3(transform.position.x, .23f, transform.position.z);

        GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>().YokOlmaEfektiOlustur(yeniPoz);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

